# PowerShell - checking for 'ctrl+c' - quickly

Tags: powershell, performance

I have a powerShell script that runs 24x7 until a user presses crtl+c to perform a controlled shutdown.

I use this simple function to check if the ctrl+c keys have been pressed

```
function fnTestForCtrlC
{
  ## Stops Ctrl+C from exiting this function
  [console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true

  if ($Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable -and (3 -eq [int]$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("AllowCtrlC,IncludeKeyUp,NoEcho").Character))
  {
    # Initiate an orderly shutdown here 
  }
}
```

The code works fine, but whilst doing some performance tuning I've discovered that this takes around 100ms every time it's called. Since the script checks for ctrl+c almost continuously, this has a big performance hit on the overall script.

Why does this function take so long to execute, and is there a better (i.e. quicker) way of doing the same thing?

UPDATE - still having problems with this. I've moved the code from the function to the main loop....

```
  $swCtrlC.start()
  $script:cntCtrlC++
  if ($Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable -and (3 -eq [int]$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("AllowCtrlC,IncludeKeyUp,NoEcho").Character))
  {
    # Initiate an orderly shutdown here 
  }
  $swCtrlC.stop()
```

`$swCtrlC` is a stopwatch, `$script:cntCtrlC` is a counter. I divide one by the other to get an overall figure of around 80ms.

So, even after removing the test condition from the overhead of a function, this simple check....

```
  if ($Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable -and (3 -eq [int]$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("AllowCtrlC,IncludeKeyUp,NoEcho").Character))
```

Takes 80ms or more.

Just to clarify the underlying issue. I'm not particularly concerned with testing for ctrl+c, I'm really just looking for a way a user can cleanly exit a continuous loop without wasting too much time checking for user-input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't much room for improvement from what you're currently showing us, the best you can do is to not use a function and put your `if` condition inside the loop and do the assignment to `TreatControlCAsInput` just once at the top of your script. Invoking a function or script block is a bit expensive in PowerShell, this is hinted in [**PowerShell scripting performance considerations**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations?view=powershell-7.3#avoid-repeated-calls-to-a-function).

Try this test:

```
$tests = @{
    'Function Invocation' = {
        [console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true

        function fnTestForCtrlC {
            if ($Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable -and 3 -eq $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('AllowCtrlC,IncludeKeyUp,NoEcho').Character) {
                Write-Host 'Ctrl+C was pressed'
            }
        }

        $i = 0
        while($i++ -le 100000) {
            fnTestForCtrlC
        }
    }

    'If condition' = {
        [console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true

        $i = 0
        while($i++ -le 100000) {
            if ($Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable -and 3 -eq $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('AllowCtrlC,IncludeKeyUp,NoEcho').Character) {
                Write-Host 'Ctrl+C was pressed'
            }
        }
    }
}

$tests.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Test = $_.Key
        Time = (Measure-Command { & $_.Value }).TotalMilliseconds
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: wow - didn't realise function performance was so poor!

Comment: hi @ConanTheGerbil is there something missing in the answer? I see it is no longer accepted

Comment: I have provided an update in the post, even after removing the function, the test still takes 80ms or longer.

Comment: @ConanTheGerbil I have already stated in my answer what you have right now cant be optimized any further than moving the code to the loop itself and not using a function. Interacting with the PSHost (Console) is expensive by itself and this cannot be optimized any further. Perhaps try using a newer version of PowerShell, pwsh 7.3+ has been greatly optimized in general.